# PHP Date not returning anything

Tags: php

I have a variable and I'm trying to assign a formatted date to it ... like now() but formatted, so I'm trying this:

```
$mydate = date("F j, Y, g:i a");
```

My problem is that $mydate seems to be empty. I need it to return the Now() date time.

What I'm I missing?

Comment: I believe you have to delete the comma after the j

Comment: Really? `var_dump(date("F j, Y, g:i a"))` gives nothing at all? How do you determine that the variable "seems" empty?

Comment: Zounds of 'works for me' answers incoming!

Comment: Guess today is not your day...may be it will work tomorrow..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine :-D

```
  <?php
      $mydate = date("F j, Y, g:i a");
      echo $mydate;
  ?>
```

ouput:

> > September 13, 2012, 10:55 am

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work fine for me?

```
<?php 
    $mydate = date("F j, Y, g:i a");
    echo $mydate;
?>
```

Output:

> September 13, 2012, 9:55 pm

How are you testing to see if it empty? If you don't feed it a timestamp as the second param, it will take a default `now()` and feed it in - but you know that already no doubt :)

Answer (score -2):

Try this without comma

```
$mydate = date("F j Y, g:i a");
```

If I print this variable I have this:

> September 13, 2012, 12:57 pm

Is What you want or not?

Comment: A comma is not a special character in the date string, it will just output a literal comma.

Comment: I bet you saw the comment by Jonathan and posted this answer

Comment: @aspirin What? I have posted at hte same time I think

Comment: i make mistakes..im guilty :(

Comment: @JonathanRomer I don't have seen your comment we have thought the same thing. Don't think that I have copy from you please

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri I suppose main problem of your answer is not a potential plagiarism; it's that it doesn't solve the OP's problem. ) Did you try to use the expression given in the question? Doesn't it work for you?

Comment: It works but immediately I have thought at that problem and sorry for my error